# How can I view files in zip from a terminal command line

Tags: zip

I want to view file list in zip archive using PuTTY without unzipping the archive.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. Try the unzip command as follows

`unzip -l <filename>`

p.s im assuming you are ssh-ing to a unix like machine?